# How to add addclass jQuery function in tab-pane html boostrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have the following html structure

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Storico</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Budget</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This tab is linked to the following tab-content:

```
<div class="tab-content p-0">
            <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart"
            style="position: relative; height: 300px;">
            <canvas class=" w-100 " id="revenue-chart-canvas"  height="300" style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart tab-pane " id="sales-chart"
        style="position: relative; height: 300px;">
        <canvas class=" w-100 " id="sales-chart-canvas" height="300" style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

I want to create a jQuery function that give me the possibility to, when I click on the sales chart button the fuction add the following class attribute:

```
<div class="chart tab-pane active " id="sales-chart"
```

Comment: do you want to add "active" class to div ? If so take a look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/ it does it automatically you are missing attributes in you tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question very well...

First, if you use bootstrap tabs, the "show" and "active" classes are moved "automatically" for each tab with the corresponding syntax. See the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs this is enough to execute a change of panel.

Instead, if you want to add custom classes to the panel at the time of activation, you can simply intercept the destination of the link and add one or more classes to the destination panel...

Look the example with inspector...

```js
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
    let target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).addClass('pippo');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <ul class="nav nav-pills ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Storico</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Budget</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content p-0">
        <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"> A
            <canvas class=" w-100 " id="revenue-chart-canvas"  height="300" style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart tab-pane " id="sales-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"> B 
            <canvas class=" w-100 " id="sales-chart-canvas" height="300" style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
        </div>            
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```